# HTML tag for user interface elements

Tags: html

I know about `code` and `kbd` tags. But is there a tag for user interface elements? To write markup like this:

```
<p>Then you should press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or just press <ui>OK</ui> button.</p>
```

Also for window titles, checkboxes, radio buttons etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a tag for user interface elements?

The appropriate element for marking up *user input* is `<kbd>`.

[From the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-kbd-element)

> The `<kbd>` element [represents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#represent) user input (typically keyboard input, **although it may also be used to represent other input, such as voice commands**).

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

So your example would be appropriately marked up using:

> ```
> <p>Then you should press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or just press <kbd>OK</kbd> button.</p>
> ```